# Error GoogleMaps SDK from CocoapPods iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

When i did install a Google Maps framework from CocoaPods

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'BeNaved' do
  pod 'TNImageSliderViewController', '~> 0.1'
   pod 'SCLAlertView', '~> 0.4'
   pod 'HanekeSwift'
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

But when im running the app it appears an error.

```
  ld: framework not found GoogleMaps
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Very need your help, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing the syntax of the podfile wrong. It is:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

You were writing it as **"8.0"** (notice the single quotes which I've changed).

Comment: Try deleting the derived data. You can find it under /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/. Run `rm -rf /Users/<yourusername>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` in your terminal and try?